# how to postpone certain time then res.redirect?

Tags: express

basically this is the goal i want to achieve,
when get '/validation'page, it sends out message first then redirect to another web page after 3 secs.

```
router.get('/validation', function (req, res, next) {
 res.send('you will see home page after 3 seconds')
  setTimeout(function () {
    res.redirect('/');
  }, 3000);
});
```

this will come up with error:can't set headers after they are sent.
i know the reason, res.send and res.redirect both send head, it is duplicated. but how to realize my goal by different way?

Answer (score 1):

If you send something, you can't send something else because of the headers.

If you want to redirect 3s later, you can just wait without sending info to the user.

If you want to send some infos to the user and display "wait for 3s" then you need to do it with javascript on the client side

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location = "http://www.google.com";
}, 3000)
```

Comment: thank you a lot, i render html page with this javascript, it works!

Answer (score 0):

When you call the `res.send` function, the execution ends: to solve your problem you should delete `res.send` which only prints a message